# How to escape quotes in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, escaping

I am trying to run this statement but it is not working

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'john' WHERE NAME = 'John'';
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases use doubling every qoute

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = ''john'' WHERE NAME = ''John''';
```

Still there is a better option in Oracle - text blocks, where any inner quotes need no escaping

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'john' WHERE NAME = 'John']';
```

More information and examples [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html)

Comment: This is giving me an error

Comment: Error starting at line 23 in command:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'john'' WHERE FULLNAME = 'John']'
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'john'' WHERE FULLNAME = 'John'" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'john'' WHERE FULLNAME = 'John'" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Error starting at line 23 in command:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = ''John'' WHERE NAME = ''john'''
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'John' WHERE NAME = 'john'" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "UPDATE TPERSON SET NAME = 'John' WHERE NAME = 'john'" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: There's an redundant quote after `'john'` in the error message. Use exact copy of the snippet from the answer.